# How to get all header text from datagrid in wpf C# using code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to get all header text from datagrid in WPF application.
Is it possible or not ?
I want to get all header text not only one header text.I want to get all header text in collection format.As we get items from datagrid.
Like:
 `DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGridUserSalesRep.Items.GetItemAt(0);`

XAML:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridUserSalesRep" TextElement.FontStretch="Normal"  FontSize="12"    FontWeight="DemiBold" ColumnWidth="100" RowHeight="50" Height="568" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1136" FontFamily="Arial" Background="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnHeaderHeight="40" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader">
                        <DataGrid.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF28689F" Offset="0.033"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </DataGrid.BorderBrush>
                        <DataGrid.Columns  >
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="currDG"  Binding="{Binding curr}" FontWeight="Normal"  Width="120" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Currency">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping"  Value="Wrap"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding profit}" x:Name="totalProfitDG" FontWeight="Normal" Width="160" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Total Profit">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping"  Value="Wrap"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn   Binding="{Binding sale}"  x:Name="totalSaleDG"  FontWeight="Normal" Width="160" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Total Sale">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping"  Value="Wrap"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="agentDG"  Binding="{Binding agent}"  FontWeight="Normal" Width="210" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Agent">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping"  Value="Wrap"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="customerNameDG" Binding="{Binding client}"  FontWeight="Normal" Width="210" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Customer Name">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping"  Value="Wrap"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="dateDG" Binding="{Binding date}"  FontWeight="Normal" Width="120" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Date" >
                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping"  Value="Wrap"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idDG" Binding="{Binding id}"   FontWeight="Normal"  Width="100" Header="S.Inv" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>
```

Code Behind:

```
    private DataTable dataTable;
    MySqlDataAdapter mySqlAdaptor;
    private MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataReader dataReader;

private void displayDataGrideSalesReport()
        {

        string    con = "SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;DATABASE=salaamhost;UID=root;PASSWORD='';allow zero datetime=true;SslMode=none";

             var   myconection = new MySqlConnection();
             myconection.ConnectionString = con;
                cmd = myconection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;



            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sales.sale_id as id,sales.datetime as date ,sales.cash_sale_client_name as client, users.first_name AS agent , sales.grand_total as sale ,sales.profit  ,sales.currency as curr  FROM sales,users WHERE sales.agent_id = users.user_id group by  sales.sale_id ORDER BY sales.sale_id";

            myconection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            mySqlAdaptor = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            mySqlAdaptor.Fill(dataTable);
            dataGridUserSalesRep.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
  }
```

See the image below.I want to get green rectangle values using code behind.

[image]

Comment: code? XAML? can you us some?

Comment: No i do not want to used XAML.I know we can give name a header and get text of those header.But i want to get all header in collection form. I am creating report therefore.I want to get all header using code.As we get all items.

Comment: yes but can you post whatever you used to define this table?

Comment: I have post code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to get all header text in collection format

If a `List<string>` is ok with you, you can just do this in your code-behind:

```
var HeaderTexts = dataGridUserSalesRep.Columns.Select(e => e.Header.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi I'm glad I could help, best regards!